# How to edit a photo after being uploaded

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

Is it possible to visually edit a photo on Facebook after being uploaded? I don't want to have to retag the people again. I accidentally forgot to remove something on the photo.

And by edit I mean not organize or categorize it in an album. Does Facebook have a photo editor that can edit any present images without re-uploading it?

Comment: Facebook only allows you to rotate the photo.

Comment: Only rotate? Dang I really wish they could implement a mini-Paint where a person can erase some parts of the photo. I mean it would be very terrible to have to retag and send them notifications again.

Comment: I agree! They really need to enhance their photo tools.

Comment: Allowing the owner to edit the photo after it's been uploaded would open too many doors for malicious actions such as adding nudity. Imagine someone uploading a photo of a cat and a grandma says "oh what a cute kitty" and then their buddy "hacks" their account and edits it into porn. At best, if editing was allowed then all involved people such as those who liked, commented, or were tagged would need to be notified of the change and decide whether or not their involvement should remain before the edit can be made public.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to do this. I edited the original photo stored in My Pictures (I needed to brighten it a little). I went to my FB post, edit/add photo. I uploaded the edited photo (privacy only me while doing this) to compare it with the photo as originally posted. It was an improvement, so I deleted the original and the new version was left, and set privacy back to "friends".
 Not a new post, all the comments remain.